# Hello World Makefile

Tags: make

Can any one explain the simple makefile give below, as i want to start with kernel module programming and i am not getting it.

```
obj−m += hello−1.o

all:
    make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise, what you are after? We do not know if there is a specific question you seem to have regarding to the example Makefile or you need a generic introduction to Makefiles. In the latter case I do not see the reason why starting with kernel development (not easy).

Comment: @ChristianWolf  yup i need generic introduction to makefile,like i know it is used to recompile the modules again and again in an easy way. But i havent been able to understand the each and every line of the makefile i have mentioned in question?

Comment: The `-C` option tells make to change to some dir before doing anything else -- so you should look at the `Makefile` from `/lib/modules/$(uname −r)/build` ;-) (hint: there are some docs in the  `Documentation/kbuild/` dir in the kernel source)

Comment: If you're completely new to (GNU) make, I suggest reading its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction). It's pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have two targets (`all` and `clean`). You can call them on the console when you are in the folder by `make all` or `make clean`. The first target is alwas the default target (`make` results in `make all`).

Indented the *recipe* is stated. This is the code that gets executed by make to build the target. So the invocation of `make` will result in the invocation of

```
make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

Of course the shell expands the `uname` command and the `M` environment variable. Then `make` is invoked in the named folder (`/lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build`) with the target `modules`. What this target (of the subprocess) does is obviously not specified in this file.
This means, that in `/lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build` there is another `Makefile`, that has a `modules` target defined. The above listed command builds/calls/issues this `modules` target in `/lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build/Makefile`.

The same holds true for the `clean` target. This will issue a subprocess with the `clean` target in the named folder.

The idea of the two targets is to have two distinguished features. One (`all`) is to build something (your module probably). The other is to clean up your work (`clean`) in case the compiling went wrong and you want to remove any non-source files. This interpretation of the targets is however only semantically from the name. It depends upon the implementation of them. You can name them `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` if you like. However is is much less readable than `all`, `clean`, and `install`.

The first line appends a string `hello−1.o` to the vaiable `obj−m`. As the variable is empty before (if not set up by external environmental variables), it is simply set to that value. However, the value is not `export`ed, thus only locally visible. <strike>So it has no effect on the subprocesses (see [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html)).</strike>

---

An additional remark:
I was wrong that the `obj-m` had no effect. The `Makefile` is reread by the kernel's `Makefile` and searched for variables beginning with `obj-`. These are then used for compiling the required object files. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21140538/882756

Comment: Why do we need two targets all and clean. And What does modules indicate in "make −C /lib/modules/$(shell uname −r)/build M=$(PWD) modules".

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect your additional questions.

Comment: thanks for your updation , can you please explain  what the words 'modules' and 'clean' mean at the end of targets.

Comment: The words `modules` and `clean` are just targets of the kernel's Makefile. These are de-facto standard names. Sorry, I do not get your problem here. They could have been called `apple` and `banana` as well, but the kernel developers decided on these target names.

Comment: Using `M=$(pwd)` the `make` program evaluates the current working directory (`pwd`) and stores it in the environment varible `M` temporary for the call of the sum-`make`. As far as I know (this is the way the LInux kernel developers build modules), the kernel's `Makefile` uses this variable to determine the location of the module to be built.

Comment: Thank You Christian , learnt a lot from you.